# Как в PhpStorm настроить сворачивание функций в стиле ES6

Tags: phpstorm

PHPStorm не сворачивает блоки для javascript такого типа :

```
cancelOrder()
{
  .....              
},
```

Особенно не удобно когда у меня vuе шаблон имеет достаточно большое кол-во методов на странице :( может кто знает как заставить его сворачивать такие методы ?

В настройках для проекта указал ECMAScript6, но толку 0 :(

Возможно есть способ самому как-то указать, задать, схлопывание ?

Comment: У меня на `Linux Mint 18 MATE 64-bit` в `PHPStrom 2016.3` сворачивает. Смотрите настройки: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/code-folding.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По каким то неведомым причинам если текст находится внутри файла *.vue,
к тэгу скрипта необходимо добавить атрибут `type="text/ecmascript-6"` и тогда блоки будут функций и условий начнут выделяться.